# Variable naming conventions for nested pure functions

Tags: functional-style, pure-function

My understanding is that for nesting pure functions, one should use the explicit version of pure functions. I would like to know the best way of making it readable for people.

I currently have defined a function that takes a list of points `pp`, and a single point `p` as input and returns a point from `pp` that is nearest to point `p`.

I have defined it as:

```
FindNearestPointToPoint[
pp_List?(MatrixQ[#,NumericQ]&),
p_List?(VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&)]/; 
Last[Dimensions[pp]]==Length[p] 
:=MinimalBy[pp,Function[PP,(PP-p).(PP-p)]]

FindNearestPointToPoint[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 5}}, {1, 10}]=
(*{{1, 5}}*)
```

What it does is, it calculates the distance between p and each point in `pp` and chooses the one with the shortest norm.

Now, as the next step I want there to be multiple `p` points and change the choice criterion to be one involving multiple points. I have currently opted for the following:

```
FindNearestPointToPoints(
pp_List?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &), 
p_List?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] /; 
Last[Dimensions[pp]] == Last[Dimensions[p]] :=
MinimalBy[
    Function[PP,
            Total[
                  Map[
                       Function[P, (PP - P).(PP - P)]
                       , p]
            ]
    ]
]
FindNearestPointToPoints[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 5}}, {{1, 10}, {1, 9}}]=
(*{{1,5}}*)
```

Now, `pp` and `p` might not be the ideal names for the original function's variables, but I would be interested to know if there is a variable naming convention for nested functions of this type.

Also would like to know if these nested functions can be made more readable and or efficient, or if there is any way of avoiding explicit `Function[]`s.

Comment: Underscores are... special in *Mathematica*. (Highlight one, press F1, see what I mean.) You don't really use them in function names like you did here.

Comment: @J.M. erm what underscores? I am using those for pattern matching

Comment: Also, take a look at `Nearest[ ]`

Comment: like in `FindNearestPoint_toPoint`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Oh I see yeah sorry I have them as FindNearestPoint1 and FindNearestPoint2 in my own code. was trying to make it more readable here.

Comment: @Shb Try to paste here your actual code. You'll shorten the write-read-comment-update by ten times (from my experience :) )

Comment: Yep did see that one. I could use it for the single point case, but it wasn't really applicable for the second case.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I'll keep that in mind. :)

Comment: `FindNearestPointToPoints[a_, b_] := 
 a[[Ordering[Tr /@ Outer[(#1 - #2).(#1 - #2) &, a, b, 1], 1]]]`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius interesting. Thanks. Could you elaborate on what the trace of Outer[..] represents? It's a rectangular matrix... It's been a while since I have any linear algebra... Should I be looking at the Kronecker product's properties?

Comment: The `Tr /@` is just adding up each row

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Oh I see. you are mapping it... Sorry I thought you were applying it directly to matrix which got me confused.